# Your project is in SDK version >= 33.0.0, but the expo package version seems to be older

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, sdk, expo

I can't start my Expo app. I am getting this error:

```
Your project is in SDK version >= 33.0.0, but the expo package version seems to be older.
(0 , _config(...).fileExistsAsync) is not a function
```

It was working properly on Monday. My expo cli and sdk versions are 36.0.0, so the newest ones. Did anyone have this problem as well and knows a possible fix for this?

I am using an Android Studio Emulator.

Just ran expo upgrade and it told me that I am already using the newest versions but I ran it anyways and it ended with this:

```
ConfigUtils(...).resolveModule is not a function
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright I fixed it by myself. Even though I had the newest cli I had to upgrade it again and then I had to change the blacklist.js file located in node-modules/metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist.js to this:

```
    var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

Comment: Any idea why this was necessary?

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities: your global installation of the expo-cli package is outdated, or your expo package in the project itself is outdated.

To figure this out, run `npm ls` in your project directory and search for the expo version.
If you're on a unix based system or have grep otherwise installed you can do this quickly with `npm ls | grep expo`.

If either of these show an expo package version less than 33.0.0 then you need to update the project's expo with `expo update 35.0.0.`

On the other hand, if the expo version in the project is above 33.0.0 then the global version needs an update, which can be fixed with `npm install -g expo-cli`

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/

Comment: This cant be the error because like I said above both my cli and my sdk are the newest possible.

Comment: There are obviously more than two possibilities because OP (and we) are still facing this issue with everything at the latest.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with both **SDK** and the **Expo client version** mis-match.
Try doing this in the terminal with **sudo** and give the password:

```
sudo expo update <version>
sudo expo start
```

Do change **<version** with the latest or minimum version the error occured at. mine was 37.0.0

Happy to Help.by **RTTSS**.

Answer (score 1):

run this:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```